# Flickering when div background-image is defined with a CSS custom property on iPhone

Tags: css, ios, angular

I have an Angular app and the logo is defined as a CSS custom property:

```
--theme-logo: url("~/assets/images/logo.png");

.logo {
  background-image: var(--theme-logo);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
 }
```

I have tested it on multiple platforms and browsers and on iPhone the logo flickers and is refetched multiple times. That happens when you scroll, click on links or in general anything that would trigger a change.

This only happens on iPhone, on both Safari and Chrome. All other desktop and mobile browsers don't have this flicker.

What could be causing this flicker or make the browser refetch the same image 20 times in 1 sec?

Comment: Simply a browser bug …? That’s what this sounds like to me. The saying “Safari is the new IE” didn’t come out of nowhere, and Chrome on that platform isn’t really a Chrome, but a re-skinned version of the same Safari rendering engine. // Can this be reproduced with a minimal HTML & CSS example, or does it “need” angular for this to occur?

Comment: @CBroe Sadly it doesn't seem to be a bug cause if I put together a simple HTML example this problem doesn't occur. I think this is either related to Angular or perhaps the flex container. There are 3 items on the page, header, footer and content. The logo is on the header. Does flex cause a redraw of the page?

Comment: Then I’d guess it is rather more likely that angular is to blame, than flexbox as a layout system in itself. Could be some DOM manipulations/updates performed by angular, that cause this? Maybe Safari thinks something is an “update”, if it gets just overwritten with the same value, whereas other browser recognize it as effectively a non-change … something like that.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue in Chrome desktop (MacBook Pro). Any viewport change calls the image again, over and over. Only thing I have found is if you have inspector open on the network tab and uncheck "Disable cache" it stops it. But that begs the question, did it really stop or is it just masked by caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, this is a bug with Safari on iOS 14.4.

A workaround is to define the background image CSS property as base64.